# How to deliver 2 int,1 float variable input in the input function to main function by using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm making bill calculater and i need to input 2integer and 1real number at input function and i need to take that 3 number to months function that calculate bill with 3numbers provided by input function.

```
...
float input(int*,int*,float*);
void months(int, int, int, int, float, float,int,int,float);
...
int main()
{
  ...
  int x1,y1;
  float z1;
  ...
  int *x= &x1;
  int *y= &y1;

  float *z= &z1;
}

float input(int*x,int*y,float*z)
{
  ...
  printf("\nInput your usages of voice : ");
  scanf_s("%d", &x);
  printf("Input your usages of text : ");
  scanf_s("%d", &y);
  printf("Input your usages of data : ");
  scanf_s("%f", &z);
  ...
}

void months(...,int*x,int*y,float*z)
{
  ...
}
```

I expect if I input `x,y,z 150,100,2.11` then 
`150,100,2.11` is put in months function either,but in months function x,y,z are trash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already get the addresses of the variables in argument in *input*, so replace

> ```
> scanf_s("%d", &x);
> ...
> scanf_s("%d", &y);
> ...
> scanf_s("%f", &z);
> ```

by

```
scanf_s("%d", x);
...
scanf_s("%d", y);
...
scanf_s("%f", z);
```

Out of that you do not need to have the pointer variables in *main*, you can replace

> ```
> int x1,y1;
> float z1;
> ...
> int *x= &x1;
> int *y= &y1;
> float *z= &z1;
> ...
> float v = input(x,y,z); /* added */
> ```

by

```
int x1,y1;
float z1;
...
float v = input(&x1,&x2,&z1); /* added */
```

And if I well understand in function *month* you can also directly give *x1,y1,z1* rather than their addresses. Note the declaration `void months(int, int, int, int, float, float,int,int,float);` does not match with the definition even partial `void months(...,int*x,int*y,float*z)`

I also encourage you to check the result of `scanf_s` to be sure the user enter a valid input

---

If I change your code getting into account my remarks :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input(int*,int*,float*);
float months(int, int, float);

int main()
{
  int x1,y1;
  float z1;

  if (input(&x1, &y1, &z1))
    printf("%g\n", months(x1, y1, z1));

  return 0;
}

/* return 0 if an input is erronned */
int input(int*x,int*y,float*z)
{
  printf("\nInput your usages of voice : ");
  if (scanf_s("%d", x) != 1)
    return 0;
  printf("Input your usages of text : ");
  if (scanf_s("%d", y) != 1)
    return 0;
  printf("Input your usages of data : ");
  if (scanf_s("%f", z) != 1)
    return 0;
  return 1;
}

/* return the bill */
float months(int x,int y,float z)
{
  return x + 1.2 * y + z *100; /* just to return a value */
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra i.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 

Input your usages of voice : 150
Input your usages of text : 100
Input your usages of data : 2.11
481
```